# How to use jquery toggle for multiple childs in different parents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically i have a few parents that have the same class:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

And when i click on a `parent` class i want to toggle its child. For that i'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.parent').click(function(e){
        $(this).children('.child').toggle();
    });
});
```

This does toggle my child but if i leave it visible and i click on the next parent i want to make all other children disappear.

Is this possible using only jquery/javascript? 
Thank you!

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.parent').click(function(e) {
    $(this).children('.child').toggle();
    $(this).siblings('.parent').children('.child').hide();
  });
});`

Comment: @emma Please check last edit of my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52185512/5104748)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a class to manage display and just toggle that class on current parent and remove it from others

```js
$('.parent').click(function(){
  $('.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
})
```

```css
.parent{ margin-bottom:2em}
.child{display:none}
.active .child{ display:block}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">Parent 1
    <div class="child">Child</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">Parent 2
    <div class="child">Child</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">Parent 3
    <div class="child">Child</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @charlierfl, it worked <3 now i can play with it however i want. Thank you so much for taking some of your time to help me<3:D

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to show only one of childs. To do this work first hide all childs then show clicked child.

```
$('.parent').click(function(e){
  $(this).siblings().children('.child:visible').toggle();  
  $(this).children('.child').toggle();     
}).children(".child").toggle();
```

```js
$('.parent').click(function(e){
  $(this).siblings().children('.child:visible').slideUp();  
  $(this).children('.child').slideDown();     
}).children(".child").slideUp();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">parent1
    <div class="child">child1</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">parent2
    <div class="child">child2</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">parent3
    <div class="child">child3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey @Mohammad, tank you for taking time to help me, it works but i will use the toggle method. Thank you again!!! <3:D

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This:-

```
$('.parent').click(function(e){
            if($(this).children('.child').is(':visible')){
                $(this).children('.child').slideUp();
            }else{
                $('.parent .child').slideUp();
                $(this).children('.child').slideDown(); 
            }           
        });
```